# How do i open an edit text popup on actionbar menu click

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to display a popup edit text when "action_guess" is clicked. i am not sure on how to go about this. here is my code:

```
    public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_guess:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "guess code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your code sample by 1 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an `EditText` in a `Dialog`, you can follow this example.
https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/

If you want it appear in the `ActionBar`, you can overlay the `EditText` inside the `ActionBar` layout and show/hide with `setVisibility()`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I decided to go a different route though thank you very much